# Access Default font

Tags: java, c#, flutter, android-studio, xamarin.forms

How can I access default font style setting using Xamarin, android studio or flutter? Is there any methods, classes or package help me?!!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use one of these Google fonts then use the official google_fonts package from the material team.

**- add to pubspec.yaml:**

```
dependencies:
      google_fonts: ^2.1.0
```

**- Override the default font like this:**

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    textTheme: GoogleFonts.latoTextTheme(
      Theme.of(context).textTheme,
    ),
  ),
);
```